# win7 x64 batch command syntax error

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

Consider following simple script

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir') do echo %%a
```

save as a.bat, then run.

It works perfect on my home pc (win7 x64), printing files under current directory,
but getting "The syntax of the command is incorrect" on my office machine (also win7 x64).

Don't have a clue why this happens, but it's quite annoying I can't install some software
because of this.

It's been verified that "run as administrator" doesn't help.

Did I do something wrong to my office machine which corrupt batch command parsing..

Comment: Open a cmd prompt and type `dir` to confirm it works.  Then try `for %a in (abc) do @echo %a` from the same cmd prompt.  Also try `echo 123` and reply with the results.

Comment: dir works, for %a in (abc) do @echo %a also works. The problem come with " /f delims="" ", without this, it doesn't complain a syntax error.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %a in ("123") do notepad` <--- are you able to test this now from the cmd prompt?  Does it open notepad?

Comment: oh yes, it does open notepad. Then the problem could be 'dir'?  for /f "delims=" %a in ("123") do echo %a works but for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir') do echo %a fails. Seems that 'dir' doesn't get executed?

Comment: That last for command works here so it's not likely to be a syntax error. You said that DIR works, and DIR is an internal command in cmd.exe so I can only suggest that you change directory to your desktop folder and try it again.

Comment: finally I get it. The reason is that the COMPSEC envrionment variable on the broken machine is "c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe" instead of "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe".  Weird but do help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get it working.

The problem comes from environment variable %COMSPEC%.

Don't know why it's changed from "C:\windows\systems32\cmd.exe" to
"C:/windoes/systems32/cmd.exe",  The forward slash screw things up.

No idea why this matters, but seems that back slash is safer under windows:-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really use command `dir` in your batch file or another command, a command which itself is enclosed in double quotes because of a space in path or has a parameter in double quotes?

If the output of a command should be processed within the loop and the command itself must be specified in double quotes or at least one of its parameters, the following syntax using back quotes is required:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"command to run" "command parameter"`) do echo %%a
```

An example:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir "%CommonProgramFiles%"`) do echo %%a
```

`%CommonProgramFiles%` references the value of environment variable **CommonProgramFiles** which is a directory path containing usually spaces. Therefore it is necessary to enclose the parameter of command `dir` in double quotes which requires the usage of `usebackq` and back quotes after the opening and before the closing round bracket.

Further I suggest to look on value of environment variable **PATH**. There are applications which add their program files directory to **PATH** during installation, but not by appending the directory to end of the list of directories, but by inserting them at beginning. That is of course a bad behavior of the installer of those applications.

If you call in your batch file standard Windows commands not located in cmd.exe, but in Windows system directory which is usually the first directory in **PATH**, like the command `find`, and the installed application by chance has also an executable with same name in the program files directory of the application, the batch file might not work on this computer because of running the wrong command.

It is safer to use instead of just `find` in a batch file `%SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe` to avoid problems caused by bad written installer scripts of applications modifying the `PATH` list on wrong end.